# Steps after PXE network boot

Tags: networking, boot, automation, pxe

I want to setup one click deployment for my computer and automatically install an OS which I will then configure with Ansible for example.

Let's say I have a PXE client and the supporting infrastructure in my network (DHCP server with PXE extensions and a TFTP server configured with an NBP file for an OS I want to install).

The PXE client has a NIC card that supports PXE and I enable PXE in the BIOS and change the boot order to start with PXE.

When the PXE client starts for the first time this will install the served OS from TFTP.

What are the steps required after that?

Do I have to change the BIOS boot order again manually or can the PXE client understand that it already has an OS and skip the process of communicating with the DHCP and TFTP servers?